# printf вывод в режиме EGA

Tags: c

Вопрос к гуру.
Как лучше реализовать вывод строки в режиме EGA по средствам printf?

Comment: EGA это же графический режим, при чем тут средства printf? Графическими функциями надо выводить строку.

Comment: Есть что-то в си для вывода в EGA режиме?

Comment: А вы под что пишете, под DOS? И какой компилятор используете?

Comment: Я пишу для микропроцессора. Мне нужна простая библиотека для вывода данных в терминал.

Comment: Все мы пишем для микропроцессоров. Вы имеете в виду, программа без ОС в реальном режиме? Тут, боюсь, помочь не смогу. Эту информацию стоит добавить в сам вопрос, чтобы другие отвечающие видели.

Comment: Да программа без ОС в реальном времени. Надо выводить данные на терминал в режиме EGA охота использовать что - то готовое.

Comment: Под что вы пишете? Куда хотите выводить? Обычно уже есть библиотеки для этого микроконтроллера

Comment: Пишу под stm32. Хочу выводить в терминал типа тератерм.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, EGA — это не только режим, но и связанное с ним железо и фирмварь. Так что вопрос вполне валидный. Ответ на него скорее всего не очень платформонезависимый. Так что без указания платформы и начальных данных (есть ли там BIOS, EGA BIOS или boot loader, например) весьма пространный.