# Tera Term перевод в EGA режим

Tags: консоль

Кто нибудь знает как можно перевезти Tera Term в EGA режим?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [printf вывод в режиме EGA](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1229667/printf-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5-ega)

Comment: Почему дубликат ? Это вопрос по терминалу.

Comment: это просто прикрытый дубликат с уточнением вопроса.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, tera term это просто клиент, который отображает то, что приходит, например, по ssh или com, и передает обратно данные от пользователя. Это чисто текстовый терминал, а EGA - это графические режимы. Ответ - никак.

Comment: получается можно только esc коды использовать ? В терминале как то рисуют.

Comment: @zhilenkov смотря какая у вас конкретная цель. Если графики рисовать на основе данных с контроллера, то возможно вам просто [Serial Port Plotter](https://github.com/CieNTi/serial_port_plotter) нужен (с контроллера просто цифры передавать, а эта программа по цифрам строит график). Если просто цветной текст, то через esc коды.

Comment: Вот скажите как сделано меню которое вызывается командой make menuconfig ?

Comment: Смотря что за меню. menuconfig - это просто одна из целей, прописанная в Makefile, там вообще все что угодно может вызываться.